# How do I get onmouseover swap events to hold through onmouseout until the next onmouseover event?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

Could someone please help me to get the onmoseover event to hold the display:block; behavior until I've onmouseover a different event?  In other words I would like to keep an event visible until I've onmouseover a different event.  I fill the answer is a simple one. I'm 2 days new to javascript.

CSS

```
.box {
   width: 900px;
   height: auto;
   margin-top: 20px;
   padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
   border: 5px solid black;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right:auto;
```

}

HTML

```
<div class="box" style='width:400px; height:auto;>

<p style="display:inline;" 
     onmouseover="document.getElementById('sometext1').style.display = 'block';" 
     onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sometext1').style.display = 'none';">
<span>some text1</span></p>

<p style="display:inline;" 
     onmouseover="document.getElementById('sometext2').style.display = 'block';" 
     onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sometext2').style.display = 'none';">
<span>some text2</span></p>

<p style="display:inline;" 
     onmouseover="document.getElementById('sometext3').style.display = 'block';" 
     onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sometext3').style.display = 'none';">
<span>some text3</span></p>



<div id="sometext1" style="display: none;">
  <p>paragraph of content for sometext1</p>
</div>

<div id="sometext2" style="display: none;">
  <p>paragraph of content for sometext2</p>
</div>

<div id="sometext3" style="display: none;">
  <p>paragraph of content for sometext3</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First html must be like this:

```
<div class="box" style='width:400px; height:auto;>

<p id="text1" onmouseover="mouseoverHandler(this.id)" style="display:inline;"><span>some text1</span></p>
<p id="text2" onmouseover="mouseoverHandler(this.id)" style="display:inline;"><span>some text1</span></p>
<p id="text3" onmouseover="mouseoverHandler(this.id)" style="display:inline;"><span>some text1</span></p>

<div id="sometext1" style="display: none;">
  <p>paragraph of content for sometext1</p>
</div>

<div id="sometext2" style="display: none;">
  <p>paragraph of content for sometext2</p>
</div>

<div id="sometext3" style="display: none;">
  <p>paragraph of content for sometext3</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Write functions for event listeners in js file:

```
var previousId = null;
function mouseoverHandler(e){
    if (previousId != e) {
        document.getElementById('some' + e).style.display = 'block';
        if (previousId != null) {
            document.getElementById('some' + previousId).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    previousId = e;
}
```

Just think about your paragraph elements as identifiers for div and have  relation between them.

Comment: Thank you PashaB.  this syntax is far more efficient than what I was doing previously.  Thank you.  However, I am still not sure about how to make the content hold being visible when I move my mouse off the trigger event. If I mouseover text1 I would like for the content to remain visible even if I move the mouse. I would like for text1 or text2 or text3 to remain visible until I mouseover a different text1 text2 or text3. As is now the content immediately goes to display:none one I move the mouse off the trigger.

Comment: Just set one global variable in js file, then set it to be equal to e (e is element id in this case) inside the mouseoverHandler function, then use if statement to check the elements id with previous one. I edited the code in answer.

Comment: I came into Javascript thinking it would be much more difficult then it is.  I just need to to think about it properly.  I'll get it.  You're the best!!!  Thank you.